# nvarchar to utf 8 encoding format conversion in Microsoft sql server

Tags: sql-server, encoding, utf-8, nvarchar

I have varchar value in sql server. I want to see this value in utf-8 encoding format. Can anyone please tell me how to convert nvarchar to  utf-8 in Microsoft sql server?

Answer (score 0):

Please note that SQL Server doesn't support UTF-8, it supports UTF-16.
Reference : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/7346/sql-server-2005-2008-utf-8-collation-charset